# Magento 2: How to add a custom JS to frontend module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, javascript, frontend

I'm building a module and I need to **load Javascript** that must be generated in my **module** (NO theme) to the **shop frontend**.

Then, when a user enters on the web, the module has to generate **js** and inject to the shop frontend.

The js has variables that I have in the database,  then I need to join it with a Block and PHTML to create it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add these files:

```
ModuleVendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

or

```
ModuleVendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/<frontName>_<controllerName>_<actionName>.xml
```

File content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="ModuleVendor_ModuleName/js/my_js.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

JS file:

```
ModuleVendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/my_js.js
```

JS Content:

```
require([
    "jquery"
], function($){
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('jquery loaded with success!');
    });
//]]>
});
```

---

To add some **controller** or block you can add the JS content above using a PHTML:

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::my_js.phtml" name="my_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: how can i call controller or block from my_js?

Comment: you can do it using jquery ajax call